# Searching and Overwritting timestamp in txt file

Tags: php, html

I have a problem in php. I was asked to do this for my college purpose. I have a basic textbox in my first page and the user is to enter a login id in it and press the login button. Once the login button is pressed the login id and timestamp is stored in a txt file separated by comma. So if it is the 2nd time user A logs in then the previous timestamp must be overwritten with the new one.

This is my code :

```
<html>
<head><title>Login Portal</title></head>
<body><center>
<h1>TPF EMPLOYEE LOGIN</h1><hr><br><br>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $myfile = fopen("data.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['id'];
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $txt=$_SESSION['name'].",".$date.",\n";
    fputs($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<form name='login' method='post'>";
    echo "Enter your login id : <input type='text' name='id' id='id' /><br><br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />";
    echo "</form>";
    }
?>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how my txt file looks like :

```
yesh,2014-10-05 10:00:42,
thilak,2014-10-05 10:00:56,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $myfile = file_get_contents('data.txt');
    $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['id'];
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $txt=$_SESSION['name'].",".$date.",\n";
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    if(preg_match("/$name/", $myFile)) {
        $results = preg_replace("/$name.*\,/", $txt, $myFile);
        file_put_contents('data.txt', $results);
    }
    else {
        file_put_contents('data.txt', $txt, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
else {
    echo "<form name='login' method='post'>";
    echo "Enter your login id : <input type='text' name='id' id='id' /><br><br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Make sure you test this carefully before using it on your real file, to ensure it doesn't harm your data. Because I don't know enough about the file itself to be sure it doesn't damage the file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (though probably not optimal) should work. However, in a real environment you would probably want to use a database or at least lock the file so it's not updated by another session between your read and write. This is untested but should set you in the right direction.

```
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$name = preg_quote($_SESSION['name']);
$lines = preg_replace('/^' . $name . ',([^,]+),/$', $date, $lines);
file_put_contents($file, join("\n", $lines));
```